# Invarience of distances in GR?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity

I was doing a question (in [Lim 1995](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KD4LyQx_1JAC&source=gbs_navlinks_s)) which I *miss-read* as follows (paraphrased & adapted):

> Given that the radius of a photon in a circular orbit in a Schwarzschild metric as measured by an observer at infinity is $R=3r_s/2$ find the **radius** of the orbit as measured by an observer located at $R$.

The actual question had *period* in place of the the bold *radius*. I am assuming that the radius as measured by someone at $R$ will indeed be different from $R$ itself (which is by direct analogy with time, which changes between two such observers). The only way I could think of doing this adapted version is by some complex coordinate transformation - my question, therefore, is:

**Is their an easy way to solve the question in the box above, is the answer simply $R$ (i.e. distances are invariant) or do we have to do some complex coordinate transformation?**

Comment: So is it the period you are after or the radius?

Comment: @Rumplestillskin The radius. I know how to calculate the period.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to make sense.  How is a distant observer supposed to measure the radius?

Comment: @BenNiehoff I think you could expand on this and make it into an answer. I.e. Talk about why it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification It's not entirely clear to me what *your* question is.  Calling $3r_s/2$ the "radius of a circular orbit" is also incorrect.  $r_s$ is just a value of the Schwarzschild coordinate.  It doesn't measure distance from the origin (if you do the appropriate integral, you'll see that distance is infinite!) So I don't see that there is a distance *any* observer can measure, whether at infinity or not.  (Assuming we are talking about a black hole, not just any object.)  The Schwarzschild coordinate $r$ is defined such that a surface of constant $r$ has area $4\pi r^2$.